# Multi core, make function called from inside function to run on second core. directshow, opencv

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, directshow, multicore

So, I've been working on a real time tracking system with opencv. A couple of days ago I had to start using directshow (which was totally new for me) because I needed higher resolution from the webcam. With higher resolution comes higher cpu usage. the cpu is running at 50% when only using directshow without ANY opencv algorithms. (I have dual core = 100% usage of one core)

So now I need to expand this system so that is uses both of my cores.

I found this nice example from microsoft And was able to run it, using both of my cores:

```
void test1(){
    parallel_invoke(
        []() { run1(); },
        []() { run2(); }
    );
}
```

This runs perfectly and I am able to use about 85% of the total cpu (with just 2 functions with loops 'n stuff).
Now I want to use this in my other system. And I don't know how to do it.

Short description of my system:

```
int main(){
     startDirectshow()
};

startDirectShow(){
     //code for creating the directshow filter graph. including iSampleGrabber filter.
}

sampleCallBackFunction(....){
      // function called for every frame in the graph
}
```

Every thing is working so far, The sampleCB is called for every frame(or at least multiple frames per second, frames might be missed when using this?!)

My idea was to let the "sampleCallBackFunction()" run on the second core (I dont want to lock it to a specific core, only use first one available)

But the example I found starts both functions at the same time, from the same place. is it possible to, in some way, to tell the system that "sampleCallBackFucntion" should be running on another core?

Another idea i had, was to just store the data in "sampleCallBackFunction()", and also set a bool "newFrameAvailable", to true. And let another thread pull data from a global array.

```
while(true)
    If (newFrameAvailable){
         get-next-frame-in-buffer-and-do-opencv-algorithm();
    }
    else{
         do-nothing();
    }
}
```

So. My question: How to make a function called from inside another function ("sampleCallBackFunction" is called from "startDirectshow")?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not quite clear, but I suppose you want to call `sampleCallbackFunction` in another thread. (functions are typically called inside another function, which makes the call stack...)

Because DirectShow, your `sampleCallBackFunction` is already most probably running on a streaming thread which is different than your main thread. Of course, all what happens on the streaming thread is burden of one logical core.

Then, if you create yet another thread at `sampleCallbackFunction`, your system is smart enough to distribute the work on available cores, that is not an issue. But I doubt if `parallel_invoke` gives you the flexibility to do what you must and I suggest looking for `CreateThread` if you really want to make another worker there.

BTW: in a GUI application, the easiest way of calling a function in another thread is to use `SendMessage`, because the call is always distributed to the thread that created the window. That call is blocking nevertheless...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are correct, I want to create a new thread for the samplerCallbackFunction, that use another cpu-core. But I wonder, why am I not able to increase the cpu usage above 50% if my systems is supposed to distribute the load over available cores? the second core is running av ~4%, and my software needs moooore cpu power :D (I've got poor video output.)

Comment: To make use of resources, you must create the worker thread first. In this case you have your main thread (mostly) at idle (just managing the filter graph), while the streaming thread is fetching the frames from the camera. A single thread cannot employ more than one logical core.

Comment: I looked into the "resource monitor", I see that my software have 7 threads active. And I also saw that a couple of times it went up to 52% cpu usage. This must mean that everything is already running on multiple cores and I don't need to care about this?!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might want to better check what exactly is overheating your CPU up to 50% with no processing. Most likely, it's conversion to RGB color space you can avoid by processing your video in another pixel format domain. Bare video capture does not need CPU usage values that high.

> How to make a function called from inside another function ("sampleCallBackFunction" is called from "startDirectshow")?

This is not really what you want to do if you want to process in parallel and/or keep capturing while processing data. The `startDirectshow` thread is a controlling thread which starts/stops processing and starts internal streaming thread as well. Synchronizing back with controlling thread will not improve performance, but will bring headaches of (a) synchronization expense, and (b) chances for termination deadlocks.

If you want to process in parallel, you need to copy data in your sample grabber callback and exit from the callback as soon as possible. Then a pool of threads, such as [`TPL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)'s or your own, will do processing asynchronously without affecting capture performance.

Comment: Sorry but I think that this is a bit to complex for me, at the moment. With Task parallel library. Do you meen something like my second alternative i question? I think i need to read up on this.

Comment: About cpu overheating. I am running this on a 1.3GHz, 3GBram, 64bit, laptop. And it is a couple of years old. With a poor graphic card. And I am converting the input, via samplegrabber to RGB. Could this be why my cpu is going up to 50%?. I am doing this directhow stuff to get data to my opencv software. Do you know if  there is a better color space than rgb to convert to? Thanks!

Comment: I am not shure about how this TPL/async i working. Should I create another task that pulls data from a stack, and if it is empty it just waits untill there is a frame available? (like the third code-block in my question?) What can I search for on google to find more information about this? Thanks!

Comment: It's up to you to decide whether you need RGB for processing or not. If you convert data into RGB, which is typical, you will have a conversion inserted automatically. It might be not obvious, but it might be severely affecting performance. For this reason, you might want to check it out and make sure you understand what is going on. However on the other side if your processing algorithm requires RGB, then you have to have it, other pixel formats won't do well for you.